# python, pandas groupby the groupby dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that I have already done a groupby().agg() using

```
df = df.groupby(['Date','Time', 'ID_Code']).agg({'ID_Code':['count','nunique']}).reset_index()
```

now it looks like this

```
     Date          Time     ID_Code  count  nunique
0    2021-01-04    10:50:00  CA_031      2        1
1    2021-01-04    12:40:00  CA_021      8        1
2    2021-01-04    13:20:00  CA_044      4        1
3    2021-01-04    13:30:00  CA_045      4        1
4    2021-01-04    13:36:00  CA_040     13        1
..          ...         ...     ...    ...      ...
433  2021-12-28    12:12:00  CA_805      3        1
434  2021-12-28    12:40:00  CA_802      3        1
435  2021-12-28    15:35:00  CA_003     22        1
436  2021-12-28     8:29:00  CA_806      3        1
```

What I now need is a sum of the count and how many times each ID_Code occurs.

```
#        the below line removed the multi index header.
df.columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'ID_Code', 'count', 'nunique']
#         the below line does not appear to work. Why and how would I fix it?
df = df.groupby('ID_Code').agg(total_count = ('count','sum'), frequency = ('nunique','sum'),)
```

What I want is:

```
    ID_Code  total_count  frequency
0   CA_031     242          12
1   CA_021      89           9
2   CA_044     148          11
3   CA_045      76           7
```

Comment: *does not appear to work* why do you think that is the case? What does it give you instead of the expected output?

Comment: It returns the prior df that after the initial groupby. I would expect that I would get a aggregated df.

Comment: That just means your `ID_Code` are all different for different timestamp. btw, all of the above could have been: `df.groupby(['Date', 'Time'])['ID_Code'].value_counts().groupby('ID_Code').agg(['sum', 'size'])`